# iOS: Launch A Custom Message To Be Handled By AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am attempting to call a method in my app delegate from another piece of code that is going to be shared between many other applications. Instead of retrieving a reference to my app delegate I'd like to simply launch a message that the app delegate can respond to if it happens to implement the right function, similar to how we can implement methods like `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` if we want to respond to system memory warnings.

Is this possible or is my only option to have a reference to my app delegate in my code and check if it responds to the selector before calling the method?

Comment: The shared code is going to be compiled in or are you referring to cross-application communication?

Comment: The shared code is going to be compiled in, but I just realized that in order for that to work I'll have to call a method dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a notification via NSNotificationCenter is probably your best bet. But I'd suggest checking out this objc.io article: http://www.objc.io/issue-7/communication-patterns.html. It's a great overview of different patterns for decoupling your code.

Comment: Great article, thanks for the link. I ended up taking your recommendation on NSNotificationCenter, it was super easy to implement.